# php global variable modifier not working

Tags: php, global, modifier

I'm using the basic php example for the global modifier, and it doesn't work for me :-|

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    global $a, $b;

    $b = $a + $b;
} 

Sum();
echo "***: ".$b;
```

Here is the result...
$ ***: 2

Is there any parameter on the php.ini that might effect this?

Comment: Is this the exact code?  Are you leaving any information out here?

Comment: of course he has - like what exact version of PHP...?

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/IsvLd for a reproducible version of the issue.

Answer (score 30):

I was also faced with your problem. As I am using a framework (Yii), I wasn't exactly aware that my code was indeed nested inside functions and, therefore, `global` wasn't behaving as expected (as explained by omadmedia and others).

My solution is pretty simple:

```
global $a;
global $b;
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    global $a, $b;

    $b = $a + $b;
} 

Sum();
echo "***: ".$b;
```

Comment: Works for Laravel as well!

Comment: This also works for the [PsySH REPL console](https://psysh.org) and the [Jupyter-PHP kernel](https://github.com/Litipk/Jupyter-PHP)

Comment: I had exactly the same problem but inside a class with global vars at the top and neasted functions. However, I was able to access those globals inside neasted functions through object's $this->myglobalvar.

Answer (score 16):

Believe it or not, I get answer: 2 as well.
This means there are indeed some cases where global is not working.

Tried finding the cause:
It seems that if you have a function and put the OP's code (which is a php.net example) inside that function, you will get answer 2.
This is a bit weird and kinda makes sense in a way...

(I'm using PHP 5.2.5 under Apache 2.2.8 in Win XP)

LE:
MY SOLUTION
OK, solved this: when you use global in the 2nd function you obviously get the superglobal variables, those available to everybody (ie. decalared outside any function), but since $a and $b are declared inside the 1st function, they are not part of that scope and are not available to the 2nd function.
My guess for a solution is to declare $a and $b global, outside the 2nd function as well, that is inside the 1st function.
!! Note that the 1st may be not so obvious due to various reasons, like your file (only containing the 2nd function) being included somewhere in the body of a different function in a different file.

Answer (score 7):

As @AgelessEssence answered, global keyword doesn't work if you have a nested function. It is obvious in his example. However, if it is not clear if a file is included. Here is the example.

```
//a.php
function f() {
    require_once('./a_inc.php');
}

f();

//a_inc.php
$a = 12;

function g() {
    global $a;

    var_dump($a);
}

g();

//result
null
```

In the code above, $a looks like a global variable. Actually, it is not because it is included in the function f() in a.php and $a is part of function f().

So, when your global keyword doesn't work, check whether it is included in a function. As the solution for this problem well explained in other answers, so I didn't add it here.

Answer (score 3):

i have the **SAME PROBLEM** like you, and finally found the answer

**working code** / [DEMO](http://codepad.org/JW4WM5S9)

```
$a=1;

function showA() {

    global $a;
    var_export($a);  

} 

showA(); // outputs "1"
```

**non working code** / [DEMO](http://codepad.org/UuIhKCPO)

```
function encapsulation() {

    $a=1;

    function showA() {

        global $a;
        var_export($a);  

    };

    showA();

}  

encapsulation(); // outputs "NULL"
```

as you can see, the problem occurs when using the *global keyword* inside a nested function definition

More Info: [php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#92868](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#92868)

Comment: What would be the best workaround to this? Since this is exactly what I need. (What i _think_ I need)

Comment: Same. I introduced this problem when adding a lambda wich would require modules. Since then i wouldnt been able to use global variables on the required file.  what worked for me was defining explicitly global variables.

Answer (score 2):

Your example code above works for me. But you can also use the [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) supervariable.

```
function Sum()
{
    $a = $GLOBALS["a"];
    $b =& $GLOBALS["b"];
    $b = $a + $b;
}
```

Global variables should not be used if you can help it though. There are better ways to make your functions. Use [parameters (arguments)](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) (maybe [pass by](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)) and [return a value](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) instead.

```
/**
 * Calculate the sum of the parameters
 * @param int|float $a one or more parameter
 * @param int|float $a, ... 
 * @return int|float
 */
function sum($a)
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    return array_sum($args);
}

$a = 1;
$b = 2;

$b = sum($a, $b);
```

With [PHPDOC](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.pkg.html) you can understand what your functions do years from now without reading the code. With a good [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) you can also get the explanation and argument order as you write the function.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could imagine going wrong is if you're assigning variables in the global scope after calling a function first. That is, your function is actually declaring the variables and then you just overwrite them elsewhere. For example, calling `Sum()` and *then* doing `$a=1`, `$b=2`.